# trying to update object attribute when checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object with many attributes, one of them is a boolean called "is_mandatory". Whenever an object of this sort is instantiated, "is_mandatory" is initially set to false.

I want to set this attribute to true/false whenever a certain checkbox is clicked.

```js
objectID.is_mandatory = (function() {
    $("#checkboxID").change(function() {
        if ($("#checkboxID").prop("checked")) {
            return true;    
        } else {
            return false;          
        }
    });
})();
```

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery. I'm new to front-end development altogether. I've tried many variations of the above code, can't seem to get this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the on change event to update your object.
run snippet below

```js
let myObject = {is_mandatory: false};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    render();
    $('#container').on('change', '#checkboxID', () => {
     myObject.is_mandatory = $('#checkboxID:checked').length ? true : false;
      render();
    });
});

function render(){
 $('#container').empty().append(`<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" ${myObject.is_mandatory ? 'checked' : ''}/>`)
 console.log(myObject);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: You never need to use `? true : false;`. Just use `!!` in front of the condition, or in this case, just use `.length !== 0`.

Comment: not sure what i'm doing wrong. this doesn't seem to be working either. versions might be different as I had to replace "() =>" with "function ()" for it to work. however, it's not even being logged when I click the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
    objectID.is_mandatory = $("#checkboxID").prop("checked");
```

Comment: Yes, this did not work. The attribute is perpetually false -- wouldn't it need to listen for an onchange event?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change','#checkboxID',function(){   
    var cb = document.getElementById("checkboxID");
    myObject.is_mandatory = cb.checked;
});
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, "$" is a function that return an jquery object, jquery has several methods in your case "change" method.

"change" method most likely return void since it is actually a shortform of  addEventListener("change").

Thus your code need to be modified. instead of returning value. It should access myObject, and set the property manually instead of returning.

or use other method like "prop" which return the value of the DOM Element.